# How to use .so in a second project in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I am doing an app in Android which uses native code with JNI and I have a question for  you.

I built some code in c++ to create .so library. then i use this .so in my project and in my Nexus 5 works fine but when I try in other devices app crashes.

I did a lot of test and fail is caused by use this .so in my project, but i don't know because in nexus 5 is Ok and in other devices no.

This is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Create `DSP-prebuilt` local prebuilt library from `DSP.so`
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := DSP-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := lib/libDSP.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := C:\libreriasSISTOLE\SP++3.0\SP++3.0\include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := nativo.cpp Parameters.cpp Pre_proc_mono.cpp Calc_ToF_low.cpp Runnable.cpp Trilateracion.cpp Tracking.cpp qr_solve.cpp r8lib.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl 
LOCAL_MODULE     := native_code
# Reference the local prebuilt:
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := DSP-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and this my logcat:

```
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at com.sistoleaudiocapture.Sistole_main.onCreate(Sistole_main.java:62)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   217 could not load needed library 'libDSP.so' for 'libnative_code.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libDSP.so' not found)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    at com.sistoleaudiocapture.Processing.<clinit>(Processing.java:11)
01-23 14:42:12.556: E/AndroidRuntime(19380):    ... 15 more
```

and finally this is my Processing class where i load native library:

```
package com.sistoleaudiocapture;
import android.util.Log;
public class Processing {

    private long retorno;
    private double prueba[];

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native_code");
    }

    public Processing() {
        retorno = init_variables();

    }

    public double[] prueba(byte[] data, int lenbytes) {

        prueba = prueba_nativa(retorno, data, lenbytes);

        return (prueba);

    }

    private static native long init_variables();

    private static native double[] prueba_nativa(long retorno, byte[] data,
            int lenbytes);

}
```

[SOLVED]

I added `System.loadLibrary("DSP");`in my Processing class before loaded native library and its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`217 could not load needed library 'libDSP.so' for 'libnative_code.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libDSP.so' not found`

You need to preload your dependencies.  Make sure they exist too.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("DSP");
    System.loadLibrary("native_code");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have just think this and its now runs Ok. But anyway I don't understand why in Nexus 5 needn't this step and other devies yes.

Comment: @TeloPenaBarreiro Probably differences in the Android NDK on the devices