# Where does a native *.so library and its headers go in an android project?

Tags: android, mobile, android-ndk

I have looked at [Use prebuilt JNI library in Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709359/use-prebuilt-jni-library-in-android-studio-3-1) and [How to use .so in a second project in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309926/how-to-use-so-in-a-second-project-in-android). The first is trying to get a library file without headers working and the other seems to be focusing on a specific issue with his build (although there's some useful information there). I'm relatively new to app development and especially to native development on android. I've gotten a build with the JNI library and some c++ code working, but that seems to be just for building from source.

It's probably a simple answer, but I haven't been able to find documentation on this specifically in the android developers [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts). I'm interested in understanding the correct (or most conventional) place to put and way to use a precompiled library (module/lib/*.so and module/include/*.h) in an android project. Would I even need to use JNI or the NDK if the library is built with another build tool? Another project I have has a native library source object (*.so) in `./obj/local`, `./libs`, and in many other folders related to JNI. I'm guessing it would be somewhere in there, but I'd like to know what is conventional.

For some context, I'm trying to work with the [essentia](https://github.com/MTG/essentia) library. I have followed the guide on compiling for Android and have a build with the general hierarchy mentioned above (essentia/lib and essentia/include) that seems to be working.